# Multiple problems with my Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520

Tags: 13.04, drivers, dell, brightness, fan

I'm having some problems with my Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520 laptop. I hope you can help me with this. I searched a lot, but found no working solutions.

**Specs:**

- AMD RADEON HD 7730M + Intel HD 4000
- 128 gig Samsung SSD
- 1 TB HDD
- Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU
- 8 gig RAM

Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

**Problems:**

1. Hotkey (FN + F4 and F5) to change screen brightness does not work
2. Battery lasts a lot less long than in Windows
3. Fan is spinning way too much and too loud.

Sensors say CPU temp is +- 60 C, although this is higher than usual. GPU is +-50 C. I don't even need the AMD RADEON HD 7730M. Can I disable this one completely? I also installed no extra drivers.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These bugs are all already known.

The hotkey bug is an issue, with the brightness, there's no fix for it, and this happens on several different laptops and hardware configurations.

The battery use issue has been known with EVERY laptop.

And the fan control issues are already known.  You can control it with `i8kutils` (install it with `sudo apt-get install i8kutils`), however I have seen other posts that this may only work with "low" fan speed and "max" fan speed, which may not help the heating issues as much.

If anything, you need to report the brightness issue as a bug. However, there's no fixes available right now for these problems (some are inherent to the Linux kernel and drivers, and that's not something we can fix easily).

<sub>(I have the same hardware minus the SSD in my Inspiron 15R SE (7520).)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Do the ATI drivers help for the fan and to lower the temp? I read it before, but I tried installing the Catalyst control center and the whole gui crashed.

Comment: @Aaron The fan control issues aren't helped that much with the ATI / AMD drivers, the issue would still exist.  As I said, there are no fixes available for these bugs.

Comment: Is it safe to install ATI drivers in a fresh Ubuntu install ? I did  so on Linux Mint 15 but it ruined the whole system GUI. Is the fan issue still not resolved till now ? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10
Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana the issue with the fan is, to my knowledge, not yet resolved.

Comment: Fan control can be done with 'i8kutils' package. Just '$ sudo apt-get install i8kutils' and configure files properly.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently